# Best way to design dynamic table of inputs. Like rate-lists

Tags: website-design, gui-design

I am trying to design a rate-list input for parking lot management system.
Where inputs are like this:

[image]

But it needs to be customizable in time field of inputs, e.g. 3-4 hours based on user requirements.

The final result should be in 24 hour format 2d matrix like this:

```
 [Cycle][0]:2   [tw][0]:5    [fw][0]:25
 [Cycle][1]:2   [tw][1]:5    [fw][1]:25
 [Cycle][2]:2   [tw][2]:5    [fw][2]:25
 [Cycle][3]:5   [tw][3]:15   [fw][3]:40
 .....          ........      .......
 .....          .......       .......  
 upto 23        upto 23       upto 23 
 [Cycle][23]:15 [tw][23]:50 [fw][23]:150
```

Currently I am using 24 row table like this:

[image]
  Which does not look good and also has lot of inputs to fill.
  Basically it's a bad design.

I'm looking for good UX design to achieve this, or anything similar.
Any help is appreciated (I am a beginner).

Comment: Why would you put it in 24hr output when the input has upto 96+ hours

Answer (score 0):

Since you are a beginner, you might want to read some more stuff about (interactive) data tables. I found these two nice articles which helped me rethink the way I handle data tables:

- [Design better data tables](https://uxdesign.cc/design-better-data-tables-4ecc99d23356)
- [Designing Tables for Reusability](https://uxdesign.cc/designing-tables-for-reusability-490a3760533)

And a tip from me:

Try to structure the data and actions based on primary and secondary importance. 
What do you need to seen/do at once and which actions could you hide and made visible as soon as they are needed? Also: are there elements that could be combined into one? Or elements that are not even important to have?

Answer (score 0):

You can place option for "Show Numberofentries per page". And then have there 5, 10, 20, 50" so user can change it. 
Some grouping would help, you can have filters / buttons on top with; 0 - 48h, 48h - 96h....